# How to generate uniqual types in class?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

I need to pass types into a class, and have each type get a unique name. Example:

```cpp
/*
  Example! This code doesn't work!
*/
template<typename... Ts>
struct MyComponent
{
   // Example:
   (using ${Ts}_${i++} = Ts, ...)

   // I get:
   // using int1 = int;
   // using int2 = int;
}

int main()
{
  MyComponent<int, int> comp;

  using type1 = comp::int1;
  using type2 = comp::int2; 

  // true
  std::cout << std::is_same_v<type1, int> << std::endl;

  // true
  std::cout << std::is_same_v<type2, int> << std::endl;
  
  return 1;
}
```

I need this type definition to use these unique types in tuples, also I would like a solution without macros.

#### Clarifying my question:

If you create std::tuple, then to access its fields you need to query them either by index or by type (but the types must be unique)

```cpp
std::tuple<int, std::string> t(3, "Hello");

std::get<0>(t) // 3
std::get<1>(t) // "Hello"

std::get<int>(t) // 3
std::get<std::string>(t) // "Hello"
```

But I want to store the same types there and get them:

```cpp
using Vector2D = std::tuple<int, int>

/*
 type_cat - my template combining types
 */
using Position = type_cat<Vector2D> // => std::tuple<int, int>
using Direction = type_cat<Vector2D> // => std::tuple<int, int>

using Player = type_cat<Position, Direction> // => std::tuple<int, int, int, int>

Player player(1, 4, 6, 3);

// This code is hard to read!!!
int dirX = std::get<2>(player); // I get 6
```

Getting fields by index does not work for me, because this code is less readable. I needed to generate unique names for its fields, so that I could retrieve data from them, example:

```cpp
using Player = type_cat<Position, Direction> // => std::tuple<Position::X, Position::Y, Direction::X, Direction::Y>

Player player(1, 4, 6, 3);
int dirX = std::get<Direction::X>(player); // I get 6
```

Declaring aliases somewhere separately does not suit me, and do not suggest changing std::tuple to struct or class

Comment: The most that can be achieved here would be a modest upper maximum of, say, four types for example. Then, it will be possible to cobble something together for types 1 to 4, as appropriate. But it is not possible to be able to do this for arbitrary number of template parameters. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Would you be okay with using a number instead of a name?  it should be relatively easy go get a syntax like `MyComponent::Element<0>` to get the type of the first element of the parameter pack.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. `MyComponent` is a template, `MyComponent::int1` can't possibly compile. `MyComponent<int, int>::int1` could compile - but that's a rather uninteresting construct, the calling code already knows the parameters. Also, in order to know that the typedef is named `int1`, the calling code must a priori know that the first parameter was `int`, which makes the typedef rather pointless. Suppose you were able to somehow implement what you want  - can you show a practical example of how you'd use this facility?

Comment: Are you looking for **strong typedef** (as [boost's one](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html))?

Comment: "Getting fields by index does not work for me, because this code is less readable. I needed to generate unique names for its fields, so that I could retrieve data from them" Than you have to use a simple hand crafted struct. If you have to write down the generated names by hand, you can give them speaking names instead and forget about the rest. It feels your requirement is not helpful for your self...

Answer (score 1):

In C++ we do not have any chance to generate "names" on the fly. But there is also no need to do it, as long we can access the data with another method. Instead of knowing that first data element is of type `int` and the name will become `int1`, we can simply access the data by index. In case of later maintenance it makes it much more flexible, as a change of data types of any of the elements do not need a refactoring, because the index is the same and the names must not be changed.

To generate structs with any amount of elements we have `std::tuple`.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    using ExampleTuple = std::tuple<int, std::string>;
    ExampleTuple comp;

    using type1 = std::tuple_element_t<0,ExampleTuple>;
    using type2 = std::tuple_element_t<1,ExampleTuple>;

    // true
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<type1, int> << std::endl;

    // true
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<type2, std::string> << std::endl;
}
```

[see it running](https://godbolt.org/z/e6567KsM4)

> I need this type definition to use these unique types in tuples, also I would like a solution without macros.

It is quite unclear what this means. To have a type which is already a collection should provide the types to reuse the type information in a tuple? Maybe you should clarify the intend of your solution.